# Reactjs routing to home page after login success

Tags: reactjs

I have created a login page and after successful login I want to move to home page.

I have created a Router in App.js file

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Header />
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={ Login } exact/>
      <Route path="/login" component={ Home }/>
      <Route component={ Error }/>
      </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

then in UserLogin component I am using fetch method for login after success response

```
return fetch('http://localhost:6020/login',
       {
           headers:{
               "Accept": "application/json",
               "Content-Type": "application/json"
           },
           method:'POST',
           body:JSON.stringify(user)
       }
       ).then(response => response.json())
        .then(function(data){
       console.log(data.error); 
       if(data.error===null){
        return <Redirect to='/login' />
       }
       else{
           console.log("not working");
       }
    });
```

In above code I user `<Redirect to='/login' />` by importing Redirect from react-router-dom still does nothing no error log nothing.

I just want to show home page after success login

Comment: Show full code, how you are calling this fetch and where you are using it.

Comment: just `window.location.href = /` I assume the **/** is the path to your home page

Comment: are you sure that `data.error === null` and it is not `undefined` I mean `null !== undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if(data.error===null){
    window.location.href = '/login'
}
```

Comment: Won't that make a server request? I believe the OP needs to do it via client side routing.

Comment: @anuragb26 it is not necessary, the job of the router is to overwrite the requests

Comment: this one worked but if you see charlie's answer I guess I have seen somewhere that too.....But it says Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: @Plootus this is the `react-router` way of doing the redirect. But you need to create your component  with `withRouter()` function which passes props to your component. I am not sure exactly why `react-router` is doing that, but behind the screens there is not other way to redirect a page in JS than `window.location.href`

Comment: @Plootus probably is because of `react-native` there is no browser history inside a native app and redirect needs to be handled differently.

Comment: @Plootus Yes, but they have `react-router` for `react-native` and are trying to keep the same API

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!data.error){
    this.props.history.push('/')
}
```

Does this work?

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: ok got it actually it is a class component there probably this is a reason this props is not working

Answer (score 0):

you can use redirection inside login page

```
class Login extends Component{
...
this.state={
   loginSuccess:false 
}
```

inside the the authenticate response

```
    .then(function(data){
       console.log(data.error); 
       if(data.error===null){
        setState({
        loginSuccess:true
})
       }
```

add the code below in render as

```
{ this.state.loginSuccess && <Redirect to="/" /> }
```